# Config Elasticsearch and Kibana with docker

Tags: elasticsearch, docker, kibana, dockerfile, ubuntu-16.04

I'm working with docker for the first time.
I successfully installed elasticsearch and kibana on docker, but when I try to connect kibana with elastic I get a red status with the following errors:

**ui settings   Elasticsearch plugin is red**

**plugin:elasticsearch@5.1.1    Authentication Exception**

I'm not sure but I think the problem is kibana doesn't pass elastic x-pack authentication.
Now, I'm trying to disable this authentication via elastic yml file, according to the instructions [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html).
But I can't find the yml file anywhere (I searched /usr/share/elasticsearch but I can't find either `config` directory or `elasticsearch.yml` file).

How do I config elastic with docker?

P.S.
I'm working with ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Debian/Ubuntu/Mint, you can find the config files under /etc folder.

**/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml**

Take a look at: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/setup-dir-layout.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering why this is even happening. With the following docker-compose.yml it's working fine for me with security enabled:

```
---
version: '2'
services:
  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:5.1.1
    links:
      - elasticsearch
    ports:
      - 5602:5601

  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.1.1
    cap_add:
      - IPC_LOCK
    volumes:
      - esdata1:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9201:9200

volumes:
  esdata1:
    driver: local
```

Answer (score 0):

I successfully run elastic and kibana using the official elastic [docker](https://store.docker.com/images/1090e442-627e-4bf2-b29a-555f57a64ecd?tab=description). Somehow, the container version in the official elastic [documention](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html) didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to start a container using `docker run` and not through compose file. (only use this for dev envs, not recommended on prod envs)

```
docker network create elastic
docker run --network=elastic --name=elasticsearch docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.2.2
docker run --network=elastic -p 5601:5601 docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:5.2.2
```

A brief description can be found here:
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/kibana-docker-image-doesnt-connect-to-elasticsearch-image/79511/4